# Trino error while querying for DELETE and INSERT after inserting semicolon at end of query

Tags: sql, mysql, presto, trino, starburst

I'm trying to connect to trino and querying to delete rows and inserting rows for my Alteryx workflow.
getting error after adding semicolon at the end of query which is a blocking currently the workflow.
The same query works after removing semicolon.
[After adding semicolon getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STZkE.png)
[Removing semicolon works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu05o.png)

I tried connecting to trino datasource using trino driver.
example query DELETE FROM test_semicolon_pg without semicolon at end which works fine.
but i expect the query should work fine even after adding adding semicolon at end of the query.

Comment: This is NOT MySQL problem and not MySQL error message (in MySQL the error code 1060 matches SQL state *42S21* with error message *Duplicate column name '%s'*). So this is a problem detected by your software pre-parser. Maybe you use query execution method which does not support batches/multiqueries, and it assumes the semicolon presence like a delimiter between the statements in a batch?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.